# Minitoc and unnumbered chapters

Tags: chapters, minitoc

I am writing my thesis and I have the following problem with the minitoc.

I would like my first chapter (the introduction) to be unnumbered. But when I use

```
    \chapter*{Introduction}
```

all the mini-table of contents of the chapters afterwards are shifted. Even worse, they are shifted in the counterintuitive direction: the minitoc of Chapter 1 only comes at the beginning of Chapter 2.

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}



  \title{Thesis}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\dominitoc[n]
\nomtcrule

\tableofcontents


\chapter*{Introduction}
Bla

\chapter{First chapter}
\minitoc

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 2}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\minitoc


\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Add `\adjustmtc` after `\chapter*{Introduction}`, see page 37 in the manual.

Answer (score 8):

Add `\adjustmtc` after the unnumbered chapter, see page 37 in the manual, section 1.3.4.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}



  \title{Thesis}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\dominitoc[n]
\nomtcrule

\tableofcontents


\chapter*{Introduction}
\adjustmtc

Bla

\chapter{First chapter}
\minitoc

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 2}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\minitoc


\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set `\mtcaddchapter` after your unnumbered chapter.

Comment: This seems more a comment than an answer...

Comment: This is a correct answer, however, a miinimal working example (maybe even a screenshot) showing that it really works would be highly appreciated.